# Android: Best way of handling continuous pulling from server?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, pull-request

To start of, i should mention that i'm a newbie in Android (Not that much experience in Java at all tbh), so be easy on me.

I am making an app that continuously pulls data from a server, and then returns data through a http post request. The question is, what is the best way to handle the actual pulling from the server? Should i be using AsyncTask or create another thread and let it run on that? Are there better methods for this purpose?

I will be pulling data every 5 minutes. (I am aware that this will drain the battery very fast, and i should definately be using Androids C2DM framework. But i have no experience in it before and i'm on a deadline, so this'll have to do until i have time to learn how to implement it.)

I'm grateful for any advice!

Comment: Consider using [Push](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/push-applications-android.html) instead of Pull.

Comment: I mentioned C2DM and why i'm not going to use it, and it uses the Push method. I simply don't have enough time to learn how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to pull the data in background (even if your app is not "opened" and the android device is sleeping)? I suppose thats what you want because you mentioned C2DM. If so..the buzzwords are AlarmManager (with repeating time)/BroadCastReceiver and maybe NotificationManager to notify the user. With AlarmManager you schedule your events (every 5 minutes) and with BroadcastReceiver you receive those events and do what you want to do every 5 minutes :)

Comment: Yes, i'm gonna be pulling it in the background even if the app is "closed". That sounds like it could work, i'm gonna take a look at it tommorow. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to C2DM, you can do the persistent TCP connection between your device and the server. Then every 5 minutes your server can push a tickle to the device. Upon being tickled, the device can request the information via Http post.

Here is some sample code on how to do that.The connection stays open in a background thread even after the app has exited

Creating and Managing a persistent TCP socket: http://openmobster.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/cloud/android/connection/src/main/java/org/openmobster/core/mobileCloud/android/module/connection/NotificationListener.java

Full Disclosure: I am the Chief Engineer of OpenMobster and I wrote this code. Please feel free to use whatever you like or just get an idea if thats what you need

Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but that is way to much for me to grasp with my knowledge. It sounds like what i need, but i'm not going to be able to implement it by just looking at a finished example. I would need some sort of tutorial to get started with it. Also, since you mentioned it as an alternative to C2DM, i assume it's a bit easier to set up? Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: you are in full control of your own server, so yes it is easy to setup than C2DM. Its just a difference between implement yourself vs re-use an existing service