# Android: continuous getting update from server

Tags: android

I am trying to create an application in which i want to get continuous data update from server to my app.

I want to update my local database in a regular time interval like whatsapp or any real time app is doing.

I searched a lot and trying different ways but cant find a suitable way to do that.

Please somebody suggest me some links or code for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Best way of handling continuous pulling from server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9807774/android-best-way-of-handling-continuous-pulling-from-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several way to get data from several in android app

1. Google provided options - [GCM](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html), step by step can be read from this [article](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)
2. I read one [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/774379/Push-to-Single-Android-Device) on code project , although i never used it but it looks good

Answer (score 1):

For Android Application GCM(Google Cloud Messaging) is the best option for continuous getting update from server.

Try This:
http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139